# Getting a null exception as model in razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an error's view in my `asp.net` mvc4 application like this:

```
@model System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Erreur";
}
<p>Take it easy</p>
<hgroup class="title">
    <h1 class="error">Erreur = @Model.Exception</h1>
    <h1 class="error">Controller = @Model.ControllerName</h1>
    <h1 class="error">Name = @Model.ActionName</h1>
    <h2 class="error">Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de la requête.</h2>    
</hgroup>
```

The controller code :

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
 {
     [HttpGet]
     public ActionResult Index()
     {
         return RedirectToAction("Search");
     }

     public ActionResult Error()
     {
         return View();
     }

     public ActionResult About()
     {
         ViewBag.Message = "Votre page de description d’application.";

         return View();
     }

     public ActionResult Contact()
     {
         ViewBag.Message = "Votre page de contact.";

         return View();
     }
```

The problem is that the `Model` is always null. What is the reason for this?

Comment: How do you show the view?

Comment: i add `<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Error" ></customErrors>` and the exception is a redirection to inexisting action

Comment: Provide controller action code

Comment: More specifically, where in your controller is your model populated and assigned to the view?

Comment: Please provide your controller action method code. Alternatively you can do something like this.http://www.prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/5/exception_handling_in_asp_net_mvc

Comment: Assuming this is the `Error` action, you are not passing a model to your view. How do you expect the model to be anything *but* null?

Comment: I had practically identical code and found it to be very unreliable. I ended up using log4net in the end to track MVC errors.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11542309/handleerrorinfo-using-mvc2-model-is-null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not even providing the error object to the view.

```
    public ActionResult Error()
    {



        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Is your example code showing the fix or is it showing the problem?

Answer (score 4):

You can pass a instance of your model object to the View() method, by instance

```
public ActionResult Error()
{
    ErrorViewModel vm=new ErrorViewModel();
    vm.prop1="This is the error message";

    return View(vm);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually this is a good question.  You do not really need to pass the model in question to the view.  What you do need to do is make sure that the appropriate filter is set.  In MVC 4, you can do this in global.asax.cs:

```
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
       filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }
```

Make sure this gets called in application_start:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {       
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder = new DevExpress.Web.Mvc.DevExpressEditorsBinder();
    }
```

Now your HandleErrorInfo model will be populated and passed to your error view automatically.