# Debug mode does not work with IsDebuggingEnabled?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I changed my error pages in mvc 4 following this discussion.

[handleerrorinfo using mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11542309/handleerrorinfo-using-mvc2-model-is-null)

The problem is that when loading my page in error condition

```
Model != null && HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled
```

ignores it and does not enter the condition.  In web.config debug mode is enabled. By publishing it ignores and does not enter the condition, not showing the error on the test server. 
This missing something? Thank you.

Comment: I was thinking it can not be the new custom class of errors that enter. will?

Comment: My fault code is right. My problem was related to javascript error .. solved. sorry guys. 
I have a question only. The # if DEBUG works when it is compiled?

Comment: No, it's not works... check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696175/razor-view-engine-how-to-enter-preprocessorif-debug